# Is there a theoretical distribution for the residuals of a logit/probit regression?

Tags: regression, residuals, logit, probit

I know there are a number of [ways to define residuals](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c3s8.html) for logit/probit regression but is there any theoretical distribution? I've also heard these residuals can be bimodal so maybe there is no closed form.